# Parse promises and loop of query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I cannot figure out how I ca apply Promise paradigm to my code.
My code doesn't work out how it should. The last 2 queries are not performed...
The first (mainQuery) is limited to <=5 items so it should be fast enough.
The pipeline should be:
query1.find()->for all elements found->if the element is of type 1 -> query2.count()->if count == 0-> save a new object

Could you please help me to fix it?
Thank you in advance,
Michele

```
mainQuery.find().then(
        function(items){
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {               
                if(items[i].get("type") == 1){         
                    var query = new Parse.Query("Invites");
                    //query.equalTo("userId","aaaaaaaa")
                    query.count().then(function(count){
                          console.log("why i don't see it in logs...??");
                          if (count == 0){
                            var invite = new Parse.Object("Invites");
                            //invite.set("userId", "aaaaaaa");
                            invite.save();
                          }
                        }, function(error){
                        response.error("Msgs lookup failed");
                    }); 
                }
            }
            response.success(items);
        },
        function(error) {response.error("Msgs lookup failed");
    });
```

Comment: have you check items.length>0?

Comment: Yes, is greater than 0, 3 to 5...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're calling response.success before the other queries have been executed.
The code should look more like:

```
mainQuery.find().then(
    function(items){
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i].get("type") == 1){
                var query = new Parse.Query("Invites");
                //query.equalTo("userId","aaaaaaaa")
                // first promise which needs to be resolved
                var countPromise = query.count().then(function(count){
                    console.log("why i don't see it in logs...??");
                    if (count == 0){
                        var invite = new Parse.Object("Invites");
                        //invite.set("userId", "aaaaaaa");
                        // instead of an resolved object, we return another promise which will be resolved 
                        // before entering the success part below
                        return invite.save();
                    } else {
                        // if there is nothing to do, we return an promise which will be resolved with a dummy value
                        return Promise.as('nothing to do');
                    }
                });
                promises.push(countPromise);
            }
        }
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function (results) {
            // we only get in here when all promises aboth has been resolved
            response.success(items);
        });
    },
    function(error) {
        // if any of the requests fail, this method will be called
        response.error("Msgs lookup failed");
    });
```

You'll find some additional information on how to chain promises on the official documentation: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-promises-in-parallel